# auditd rules - what order are they loaded?

Tags: audit, audit-logging

I am new to auditd, but I want to have a few auditd rule sets, one base set which will apply to all hosts, and others which will only apply to specific hosts.

My question is, if I define the rules in three files:

- /etc/audit/rules.d/set1.rules
- /etc/audit/rules.d/set2.rules
- /etc/audit/rules.d/set3.rules

Which order are they loaded?  Currently the first directive in my audit.rules file is -D which deletes all existing rules.  I assume I should only have a -D directive in the first file loaded, which is why I'm asking the question.

Any ideas?

Thanks

I have tested various scenarios, and in most cases having -D at the top of all the files deletes most of the other rules.

Comment: Don't worry.  I just found the README file in /usr/share/audit/sample-rules:

Comment: The rules will get processed in a specific order based on their natural
sort order. To make things easier to use, the files in this directory are
organized into groups with the following meanings:

10 - Kernel and auditctl configuration
20 - Rules that could match general rules but we want a different match
30 - Main rules
40 - Optional rules
50 - Server Specific rules
70 - System local rules
90 - Finalize (immutable)